# MySql convert select query to update

Tags: mysql, select, database-table

I have been struggling with a MySQL update query for some time, but cannot figure out the solution.

I have

```
Table_Items:
- id
- desc
- maintenance_times
```

and

```
Table_Maintenances:
- id
- Item_id
- maintenance_desc
```

They are related to each other like

```
Table_Items.id=Table_Maintenances.Item_id
```

Now i want to count number of maintenances from table `Table_Maintenances` for every item and update column `maintenace_time` in `Table_Items`.

I have a select query which works, but cannot figure out how to update every row (`maintenance_times`) in `Table_items`:

```
SELECT COUNT(b.Item_id) 
FROM `Table_Items` AS a
LEFT JOIN Table_maintenances as B ON a.id=b.Item_id 
GROUP BY b.Item_id
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268416/sql-update-with-sub-query-that-references-the-same-table-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out finally thanks to your example:

```
UPDATE 
  Table_Items m,
  (
    SELECT a.id, COUNT(b.Item_id) cnt 
    FROM `Table_Items` AS a
    LEFT JOIN Table_Maintenances as B on a.id=b.Item_id
    GROUP BY b.Item_id
  ) q
SET m.maintenance_times = q.cnt
WHERE m.id = q.id
```