# MYSQL UPDATE with nested SELECT from different databases

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have two databases: zeus and hades. Both databases have a field called wxrecord. On Hades the wxrecord is a Unix timestamp.

I create a new record in zeus.alldata using a SELECT/INSERT from hades.wxdata. This includes the wxrecord from hades.wxdata.

Once the new record is created on zeus.alldata, I need to run some math calculations and then update a single column with the output of that calculation.

I would like to update zeus but only update the specific record on zeus that corresponds to its counterpart record in hades. I want to match the max wxrecord on both and update so long as they are equal.

Here is what I have tried:

```
UPDATE zeus.alldata SET A='50' WHERE (SELECT max(wxrecord) FROM zeus.alldata)  = (SELECT max(wxrecord) FROM hades.wxdata);
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'alldata' for update in FROM clause
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In general you cannot UPDATE and SELECT one and the same table within one query like that. You can try to make `INNER JOIN` of `alldata` table into the query. See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268416/sql-update-with-sub-query-that-references-the-same-table-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case, I presume you actually want this query:

```
UPDATE zeus.alldata
    SET A = '50'
    WHERE wxrecord  = (SELECT max(wxrecord) FROM hades.wxdata);
```

This will update the record in `zeus` that has the maximum record value in `hades`.